# Angular InjectionToken in NgModule import array?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ng-modules

I need to use the `environment.production` flag in an import array of a NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  import: [
    ...
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
  ]
}
```

But we've multiple possible environment files at this time, that's why we use an InjectionToken in other parts of the code.

Is there a possibility to use the injection token in the import array?

Comment: I believe you would need to use the `forRoot` pattern, which allows you to pass parameters to the module when importing it in the app. Does that sound like it makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it does, but I was hoping for an easier solution :D

Comment: Haha I understand, but it's not very complicated ^^ would you like me to post an example?

Comment: No need, already done it in other modules. Thanks! :)

Comment: @WillAlexander I changed my mind, I need an example :D
With `forRoot` I can change the providers, but not the imports , at least I don't know how..

Comment: Rereading this, I can see the issue. There are a few different options. Can you tell me more about your specific use case? Do you import different versions of modules depending on the environment?